# map unequal length of array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of object data  that is the unequal length I just want to create a third array that is given below

first input array data

```
let firstArray = [{
    id: '0',
    name: 'shanu',
    age: '21'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'bhanu',
    age: '21'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'chary',
    age: '21'
  },
]
```

second set of array of data

```
let secondArray = [{
    id: '10',
    name: 'shanu',
    age: '28'
  },
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'raanu',
    age: '29'
  },
  {
    id: '12',
    name: 'chary',
    age: '30'
  },
  {
    id: '15',
    name: 'kushal',
    age: '31'
  },
]
```

output array-
if second set name watch with first set of data replace the second set id with first set it

```
let outputArray = [{
    id: '0',
    name: 'shanu',
    age: '28'
  },
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'raanu',
    age: '29'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'chary',
    age: '30'
  },
  {
    id: '15',
    name: 'kushal',
    age: '31'
  },
]
```

I'm not able to figure out how to map and filter together two different length of carry of array of object

Comment: Please clarify what shoulb be in third array, it is not clear

Comment: if the second array name is matched  with the first array name then replace second array id with first array object element ,also you can observe output array

Comment: I think it may be done with a simple `.find`. Will try to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the `secondArray` and replace the `id` if `name` is found in `firstArray`:

```js
let firstArray = [
  { id: '0', name: 'shanu', age: '21' },
  { id: '1', name: 'bhanu', age: '21' },
  { id: '2', name: 'chary', age: '21' }
]

let secondArray = [
  { id: '10', name: 'shanu', age: '28' },
  { id: '11', name: 'raanu', age: '29' },
  { id: '12', name: 'chary', age: '30' },
  { id: '15', name: 'kushal', age: '31' }
]

let thirdArray = secondArray.map((item) => {
  let found = firstArray.find((i) => i.name === item.name)
  return { ...item, id: found ? found.id : item.id }
})

console.log(thirdArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Loop through the 2nd array,
look for name matches in the 1st array,
If a match exists, update the 2nd array.

```
for (i=0;i<secondArray.length;i++){
  for(j=0; j<firstArray.length; j++){
    if(secondArray[i].name == firstArray[j].name){
      secondArray[i].id = firstArray[j].id
    } 
  }
  outputArray[i] = secondArray[i]
}
```

The output array would be the same as your 2nd array. If you don't want to change anything in your 2nd array, you could copy the array first and then make the changes in the double for-loop on the output array instead of the second array.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a look up based on the name. I would then loop over the objects and if the name exists, update the age. If the name does not exist, add the item to the array.

```js
const firstArray = [{
    id: '0',
    name: 'shanu',
    age: '21'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'bhanu',
    age: '21'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'chary',
    age: '21'
  },
]


const secondArray = [{
    id: '10',
    name: 'shanu',
    age: '28'
  },
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'raanu',
    age: '29'
  },
  {
    id: '12',
    name: 'chary',
    age: '30'
  },
  {
    id: '15',
    name: 'kushal',
    age: '31'
  },
]

// create a look up object based off the name
const data = firstArray.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.name] = { ...item } ;
  return obj;
}, {});


secondArray.forEach(item => {
  // does it exist? if yes, set the age
  if (data[item.name]) {
    data[item.name].age = item.age;
  } else { // if no copy over the object
    data[item.name] = { ...item };
  }
});

//Get your array of Objects
console.log(Object.values(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

The below may be one method to achieve the desired objective:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const updateId = (arr1, arr2) => ( // arr1 has the up-to-date / current "id"
  arr2.map(({name, ...rest}) => (
    arr1.some(ob => ob.name === name)
    ? {name, ...rest, id: arr1.find(ob => ob.name === name)?.id}
    : {name, ...rest}
  ))
);

const firstArray = [{
    id: '0',
    name: 'shanu',
    age: '21'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'bhanu',
    age: '21'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'chary',
    age: '21'
  },
]

const secondArray = [{
    id: '10',
    name: 'shanu',
    age: '28'
  },
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'raanu',
    age: '29'
  },
  {
    id: '12',
    name: 'chary',
    age: '30'
  },
  {
    id: '15',
    name: 'kushal',
    age: '31'
  },
];

console.log(updateId(firstArray, secondArray));
```

**Explanation**

- iterate over `arr2` (ie, 'secondArray')
- for `name`, check if `arr1` (ie, 'firstArray) has a match
- if yes, update the id by using `.find`
- else, keep the info in `arr2` iteration as-is